# ¿Cual seria la forma mas optima de crear un maestro detalle?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta duda, sobre como crear el maestro detalle usando como motor `MSSQL`

Mi duda radica en como hacer la relación de la tabla detalle con la maestra, dado que el `id` de la tabla maestro no sera  `identity` porque va compuesta así `COD001` entonces no podría usar `@@Identity` para llevarme ese dato al detalle, pensaba en crearla como la tengo en el ejemplo

La estructura es la más común:

> Maestro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Aunque no sea Identity, que te impide crear el detalle con la misma clave?

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, no es que algo me lo impida, solo quisiera saber si como la cree es una forma optima o si quizas estoy fallando en algo

Comment: no podemos responder eso, porque en base de datos no hay un manual de estilo para estas cosas. Habria que ver tus reglas de negocios. No importa como se forme tu clave, si el registro detalle apunta al padre, es correcto.